# Sharepoint Intermittent 403 Error

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, permissions, wss-3.0, http-status-code-403

I have a virtual server running Windows Server 2008 r2 onto which I have installed Windows Sharepoint Services 3. My SQL server is also a VM running MSSQL 2008 on Windows Server 2008 r2. I am using windows authentication NTLM.

I restored the site collection from an old Farm using Stsadm and all works fine... except that every so often, when I try to access the site, it gives me the message...

```
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

Trying to access the Default.aspx also fails with a 401.

About 15-30 minutes later it will be working again. Then it will stop again and the cycle repeats.

It is driving me mental. Any ideas?

Comment: I have deleted the machine and I am starting again from scratch. Will update question if it reoccurs.

Answer (score 0):

You might try resetting the admin password, and verifying the ID the app pools are using.

Comment: Which admin password? It is on a Domain so I'm sure that admin password is right. The service and app pool accounts are all correct. If those passwords were wrong would it give intermittent connection?